# Updating a dynamically added up sub arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, recursion, foreach

I am creating a tree structured menu just like wordpress. I am able to do it just like wordpress.  My UI just looks like this:

[image]

Here the user can add how many ever submenu's they need.
JSON Code format below :

```
[
   {
      "layout":0,
      "layouttype":1,
      "deleted":0,
      "new":0,
      "deleter":0,
      "slug":"Home",
      "name":"Home",
      "id":"12122017033717-1"
   },
   {
      "layout":0,
      "layouttype":4,
      "deleted":0,
      "new":0,
      "deleter":0,
      "slug":"About",
      "name":"About",
      "id":"12122017033717-2"
   },
   {
      "layout":0,
      "layouttype":1,
      "deleted":0,
      "new":0,
      "deleter":0,
      "slug":"Services",
      "name":"Servicessss",
      "id":"12122017033717-3",
      "children":[
         {
            "layout":0,
            "layouttype":6,
            "deleted":0,
            "new":0,
            "deleter":1,
            "slug":"Services-1",
            "name":"Services 1",
            "id":"12122017033717-4"
         },
         {
            "layout":0,
            "layouttype":1,
            "deleted":0,
            "new":0,
            "deleter":1,
            "slug":"ss",
            "name":"ss",
            "id":"12122017033920-1",
            "children":[
               {
                  "layout":0,
                  "layouttype":1,
                  "deleted":0,
                  "new":0,
                  "deleter":1,
                  "slug":"fddzfsdz",
                  "name":"fddzfsdz",
                  "id":"12122017040829-1"
               },
               {
                  "layout":0,
                  "layouttype":3,
                  "deleted":0,
                  "new":0,
                  "deleter":1,
                  "slug":"fddzfsdzfcg",
                  "name":"Sarath",
                  "id":"12122017040829-2"
               },
               {
                  "layout":0,
                  "layouttype":1,
                  "deleted":0,
                  "new":0,
                  "deleter":1,
                  "slug":"asassssss",
                  "name":"asassssss",
                  "id":"12122017041219-1"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

And current code to fetch and update one submenu comes.

```
$arr = json_decode($arr);
foreach($arr as $item) {
    $menuid = $item - > id;
    if ($menuid == $id) {
        $item - > layouttype = $page_layout;
    }
    if (property_exists($item, 'children')) {
        foreach($item - > children as $innerRow) {
            $submenuid = $innerRow - > id;
            if ($submenuid == $id) {
                $innerRow - > layouttype = $page_layout;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to edit the data 'layouttype' dynamically.  I tried using `foreach()` and it's working fine for one or two subs of submenu's, but if the user adds more subs of submenu's the code will not accommodate.

So can someone tell me the best possible way that this foreach loop can be amended so that it works based on the number of sub of sub menu's?

Comment: Instead of get all menus data... Just get first menu data. After that use ajax for get child menu data. It will save your code. And application loads faster...

Comment: @GyandeepSharma Hi thank you for the response. but i couldn't catchup your point.Can you give an example.

Comment: Sarath Hari, Gyandeep Sharma probably wants to suggest using client-side javascript instead of backend processing. I agree to this, as this will be less loading time, (maybe) faster rendering and less server load.

Comment: Look ... 
You have a menu of level 3. So Just fetch level 1 menu. After that by clicking any one of level 1 menu level 2 menu of that clicked item fetch that submenu and show in bottom of clicked item. This functionality can be don by [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you want indefinite/infinite nesting, you need to use recurrent functions.

E.g. (pseudocode)

```
function recurrentMenuProcess(branch) {
    foreach (item in branch) {
        //processing here
        if (item.hasChildren) {
            recurrentMenuProcess(item);
        }
    }
}
recurrentMenuProcess(json);
```

Comment: Hi seems some more close, thank you.you have any reference link?

Comment: Wha do you mean by reference link? =)